# How to fix the TypeError (list indices must be integers, not str) in this program?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror, indices

In one of the program I am using, I am getting a `TypeError` when trying to mine/parse a value out of `dict type` data.

Below is a brief part of that python program:

```
for c in results:
        print('value of c : ', c, type(c)) # what I added to see the issue with dict data
        for ci, lr in c['chain_info'].iteritems():
            outfile = open(lr.output_file, 'a')
            write = outfile.write

            if lr.number_vcf_lines > 0:
                write(CHAIN_STRING.format(CHAIN_STRING,
                            from_chr=c['chrom'], from_length=lr.chromosome_length,
                            from_start=0, from_end=lr.chromosome_length,
                            to_chr=c['chrom'], to_length=lr.end_length,
                            to_start=0, to_end=lr.sums[0] + lr.last_fragment_size + lr.sums[2], id=c['chrom']))
                write("\n")
```

**Full traceback error message**

```
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
Error Value: list indices must be integers, not str
/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools/vcf2chain.py:456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/bin/g2gtools", line 4, in <module>
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('g2gtools==0.1.31', 'g2gtools')
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 744, in run_script
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1499, in run_script
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.31-py2.7.egg-info/scripts/g2gtools", line 117, in <module>
    G2GToolsApp()
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.31-py2.7.egg-info/scripts/g2gtools", line 75, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.31-py2.7.egg-info/scripts/g2gtools", line 90, in vcf2chain
    g2gtools.g2g_commands.command_vcf2chain(sys.argv[2:], self.script_name + ' vcf2chain')
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools/g2g_commands.py", line 375, in command_vcf2chain
    vcf2chain(args.input, args.fasta, args.strain, args.output, args.keep, args.passed, args.quality, args.diploid)
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/envs/g2gtools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools/vcf2chain.py", line 493, in vcf2chain
    raise G2GError("Execution halted")
g2gtools.exceptions.G2GError: Execution halted
```

The github location of the file: https://github.com/churchill-lab/g2gtools/blob/master/g2gtools/vcf2chain.py

Looks like problem is with line:

```
from_chr=c['chrom'], from_length=lr.chromosome_length,
```

And, the Chain_string is something Author created as:

```
CHAIN_STRING = "chain 1000 {from_chr} {from_length} + {from_start} {from_end} " + "{to_chr} {to_length} + {to_start} {to_end} {id}"
```

I tried to print the values of that dict (by adding a print statement) to see what was the issue.

```
print('value of c : ', c, type(c)) # gave me
('value of c : ', {'chrom': '1', 'stats': OrderedDict([('ACCEPTED', 0)]), 'chain_info': {'right': <g2gtools.vcf2chain.VCFtoChainInfo object at 0x7fe9de396dd0>, 'left': <g2gtools.vcf2chain.VCFtoChainInfo object at 0x7fe9d9252d50>}}, <type 'dict'>)
```

So, what is the issue here? 
What is the problem with this data/program??

Comment: A full Traceback would be useful.

Comment: @glibdud: I thought people would be asking for full traceback, but sometime long questions don't attract attention. I just put the full traceback.

Comment: I'd recommend the full traceback after the code

Comment: Just, added the full traceback after the code.

Comment: What is CHAIN_STRING.  If it's a string and you are using its `.format` method, are you intentionally passing itself back to the original string?

Comment: I just added some information I could fine on `CHAIN_STRING`. Can you have a look.

Comment: I would assume its `from_chr=c['chrom']` since that's an `int` stored as a string.  You can narrow it down further by putting each statement on a separate line.

Comment: yes, it's from `from_chr=c['chrom']`. It actually has both int and str type data. But, the weird part is it's asking for indices of that `chrom` which could be `2 or chr_3`. I tried to remove all the lines that have string type values (like chr_3) for `chr` just to test, but still the problem persists

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon: Can you please give me a brief solution in writing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146100/discussion-between-brian-m-sheldon-and-everestial007).

Comment: `print('value of c : ', c, type(c)) ` what is the type of `c` then? It seems to be a string

Comment: yes it is a string

Comment: @gefei if you would like to read the progression in the discussion above we are trying to narrow this down to a minimal verifiable reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you say `c` is a string, then
`from_chr=c['chrom']` does not work, because you cannot give a string an index which is a string.

```
In [3]: c = 'my string'

In [4]: c['chrom']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a201470ce4c5> in <module>()
----> 1 c['chrom']

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Your error message says `list indices must be integers, not str`. I guess `c` is a list then. In both cases, you cannot give `c` a string as an index.

Comment: c is `dict type` in the starting for-loop `for c in results`, but `list type` in the write statement (after `if lr.number_vcf_lines > 0:`).

Comment: how is that possible. where did `c` change its type?

Comment: I tried `try , Except TypeError` to test it, and that seems to be the case in this program. Its weird, I am surprised too.

Comment: Looks like the 2nd nested for loop `for ci, lr in c['chain_info'].iteritems()` changed the values and types of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that, in the proceeding for-loop, the `variable c` was returning as list:

```
for c in lr.chain_entries:
   write("\t".join(map(str, c)))
   write("\n")
```

which returned `c` as list when reading another line. I had to mine `c['chrom']` expecting it to be an `dict type`. But, this variable was changed by proceeding forloop causing all the trouble.